# Get id from input which is inside of li

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to add the text from that input to my database but it only gets data from the first element in li. The problem is with $("input#todo_id-" + currentID).val(), what changes will I need to make? Thanks in advance for assistance.

```
<li id="todo-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="todo">
<input id="todo_id-'.$this->data['id'].'" type="text" class="category">
<a id="addCategory" href="#" >Save</a>   
</li>
```

jquery:

```
$('#addCategory').live("click",(function(e){        
$.get("ajax.php",{'text':$("input#todo_id-" + currentID).val(),"id":currentID.data('id'),'action':'new_category' },function(msg){
        $(msg).hide().appendTo('.categoryList').slideDown();
});
    e.preventDefault();
}));

currentID = $(this).closest('.todo');
```

Comment: This seems unrelated to php, can you post the generated html?

Comment: `id` attributes need to be unique. Try using a class for `addCategory` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want the ID of the li that was clicked. You need to set currentID inside your handler for that to work. Also, as written, currentID isn't the actual id string, it's the jQuery of the element.

```
$('#addCategory').live('click', function(e) {
    var currentID = $(this).closest('.todo');
    $.get("ajax.php",
          {
              'text':currentID.find("input:first").val(),
              'id':currentID.attr("id"),
              'action':"new_category"
          },
// etc. etc.
```

Note that as Horen pointed out, I use .attr() not .data(); Horen is also right about .live() being deprecated in favor of .on()

Answer (score 1):

`currentID = $(this).closest('.todo');` is a jQuery object not an ID.
If you want an ID use: `currentID = $(this).closest('.todo').attr('id');`

Then remember to change your `$.get()` call parameter ìd to `"id":currentID`

btw:

it's `attr('id')` not `data('id')`
`live()` is deprecated. use `on()` instead